# How to get line number of the file in apache beam dataflow?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm reading a file using **TextIO.read()** how can I get the line number of the file Or how to maintain our own distributed counter so that I can access the last value and set into the pojo.

Eg: File looks like

```
TRANSACTION_ID|CLIENT_ID|PRODUCT_CODE 
123|1001|2001
124|1002|2002
```

After reading this content I have one transform which parse into Java pojo class and if you see the pojo one field is **lineNumber** and then same pojo I'm inserting into database.

```java
class BatchData {
   private Integer transactionId;
   private Integer clientId;
   private Integer productCode;
   private Integer lineNumber;
}
```

Do we have any way to get the line number directly.

What I tried but didn't work.

1. First I tried to create my own custom counter using locking and while parsing the file into POJO then I'm calling this **getAndInc()** method.

```java
public class CustomizedCounter implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 368687587598L;

    private static int counter = 0;
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    
    public int getAndInc() {
       lock.lock();
       try {
           counter++;
       } finally {
         lock.unlock();
       }
      return counter;
    }
 
}
```

This didn't work with big file when there are multiple workers.

2. Then I though to use the Metrics counter which is provided by the apache beam but we can only use it for maintaining the counter not the actual **lineNumber** of the file. But my requirement will be fine even if I successfully able to maintain the distributed counter. I took the ref. of below doc which provides 3 types of counter but I can't able to access the last value of the counter at the runtime.

[https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#metrics][1]

Comment: I am not sure it's possible, because `Beam` and `Dataflow` distribute the computation in parallel ? The line numbers can't be added directly in the CSV lines ?

Comment: okay but can we maintain our own counter so that I can use it in the place of lineNumber

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

1. Using Beam transform TextIo.Read() to read the file.
2. Count using Count.globally(), producing a PCollection of type Long with single element - the count.
3. Use MapElement.via with a custom function to print the count to std out.

   package com.roizaig.beam.example;

   import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;

   import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;

   import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;

   import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;

   import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.*;

   import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

   public class ReadingFile {

   ```
   private static class PrintElementFn extends DoFn<String, Void> {

       @ProcessElement
       public void processElement(@Element String input) {
           System.out.println(input);
       }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory
               .fromArgs(args)
               .create();
       Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

       PCollection<String> lines = p
               .apply(
                       "ReadMyFile",
                       TextIO.read().from("src/main/resources/king-lear_TXT_FolgerShakespeare.txt")
               );


       PCollection<Long> counter = lines.apply(Count.<String>globally());
       counter.apply(MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<Long, Long>() {
           @Override
           public Long apply(Long input) {
               System.out.println("Count is: " + input);
               return input;
           }
       }));

       p.run().waitUntilFinish();
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: actually my question is different, I wanted that how can I get the line number which is read by that worker, the solution you provided will give me the total count of the file.

Comment: Do you mean what line-number each worker is working on ?

Comment: yes exactly, how can I get the line number on which the worker is running.